# Observe call not updating dictionary value. Problem with async

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get a list of images from my firebase database. Inside the observe method, if I print the number of posts it works correctly. If I print the number of posts outside the observe function, but still inside the fetchPosts() function, I get 0. If I print the number of posts after the fetchPosts() call (the function that uses observe), I get 0.

How can I save the values to my dictionary posts inside of this async call? I've tried completion and dispatch groups. I might not have implemented them correctly so if you see an easy way to do it then please help me out. Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseUI
import SwiftKeychainWrapper

class FeedViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{


    @IBOutlet weak var collectionview: UICollectionView!

   //var posts = [Post]()


    var posts1 = [String](){
    didSet{
    collectionview.reloadData()
    }
    }
    var following = [String]()
    //var posts1 = [String]()
    var userStorage: StorageReference!
    var ref : DatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        fetchPosts()


    }

//    func lengthyTask(completionHandler: (Int) -> Int)
//    {
//        let result = completionHandler(42)
//        print(result)
//    }
//
//    lengthyTask(completionHandler: { number in
//        print(number)
//        return 101
//    })
//
    func  fetchPosts() {
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
        let uids = Database.database().reference().child("users")
        uids.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let dict = snapshot.value as! [String:NSDictionary]
            for (_,value) in dict {
                if let uid = value["uid"] as? String{
                    self.following.append(uid)
                }
            }
        ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot2) in
            let dict2 = snapshot2.value as! [String:NSDictionary]
            for(key, value) in dict{
                for uid2 in self.following{
                    if (uid2 == key){
                        for (key2,value2) in value as! [String:String]{
                            //print(key2 + "this is key2")
                            if(key2 == "urlToImage"){
                                let urlimage = value2
                                //print(urlimage)
                                self.posts1.append(urlimage)
                                self.collectionview.reloadData()
                                print(self.posts1.count)

                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            })
            self.collectionview.reloadData()
        })
    //ref.removeAllObservers()
    //uids.removeAllObservers()
    print("before return")
    print(self.posts1.count)


    //return self.posts1
    }
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) ->Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts1.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PostCell", for: indexPath) as! PostCell
        cell.postImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: posts1[indexPath.row]))
        //creating the cell
        //cell.postImage.downloadImage(from: self.posts[indexPath.row])
//        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: self.posts[indexPath.row].pathToImage)
//
//
        print("im trying")

        //let stickitinme = URL(fileURLWithPath: posts1[0])
        //cell.postImage.sd_setImage(with: stickitinme)

        //cell.authorLabel.text = self.posts[indexPath.row].author
        //cell.likeLabel.text = "\(self.posts[indexPath.row].likes) Likes"

        return cell
    }


    @IBAction func signOutPressed(_sender: Any){
           signOut()
           self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toSignIn", sender: nil)
       }

    @objc func signOut(){
           KeychainWrapper.standard.removeObject(forKey:"uid")

           do{
               try Auth.auth().signOut()
           } catch let signOutError as NSError{
               print("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
           }
           dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
       }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: Delete the (pointless) `print` lines outside of the closure and do the things you have to do inside the closure.

Comment: I really have no idea how to use closures. I just googled them and this came up. I know of the completion handler, but nobody actually tells you how it works. I'm just trying to load a collection view, but I still don't know if that will work once I get the "posts" dictionary populated. Can you help me out with the closure syntax?

Answer (score 1):

You need only a few slightly changes

1. Declare `posts1` simply

   ```
   var posts1 = [String]()
   ```

   and remove the property observer `didSet`
2. Delete the line `self.collectionview.reloadData()` right after `self.posts1.append(..`
3. Move the last occurrence of `self.collectionview.reloadData()` one level up, wrap it in a `DispatchQueue` block to update the collection view on the main thread and delete the `print` lines after the outer closure

   ```
              }
              DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  self.collectionview.reloadData()
              }
           })
       })
   }
   ```
4. And there is a typo in the second closure. It must be

   ```
   let dict2 = snapshot2.value as! [String:NSDictionary]
   for(key, value) in dict2 {
   ```

   Variable names with trailing indices are pretty error-prone, better would be for example `userDict` and `postDict`

**Edit** :

This is the code with the order of execution

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionview.dataSource = self
    collectionview.delegate = self
    // 1
    fetchPosts()
    // 5 
}

func fetchPosts() {
    // 2       
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
    let uids = Database.database().reference().child("users")
    // 3
    uids.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        // 6
        let dict = snapshot.value as! [String:NSDictionary]
        for (_,value) in dict {
            if let uid = value["uid"] as? String{
                self.following.append(uid)
            }
        }
        // 7
        ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot2) in
            // 9
            let dict2 = snapshot2.value as! [String:NSDictionary]
            for(key, value) in dict2 { // TYPO!!!!
                for uid2 in self.following{
                    if (uid2 == key){
                       for (key2,value2) in value as! [String:String]{
                            //print(key2 + "this is key2")
                            if(key2 == "urlToImage"){
                                let urlimage = value2
                                //print(urlimage)
                                self.posts1.append(urlimage)
                                print(self.posts1.count)

                            }
                       }

                    }
                }
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
               // 11
               self.collectionview.reloadData()
            }
            // 10
        })
        // 8
    })
    // 4
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. posts1 is still empty after returning. Any other ideas? Thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: If the line `print(self.posts1.count)` in the closure prints the correct number of posts then the collection view must display the data, at least `"im trying"`. Do not run code ***underneath*** the closures in the same method.

Comment: what do you mean by closures? Are you talking about underneath the "observe" calls? wrapping in dispatch queue still doesn't work. I can't get "I'm trying" to print either. Can you maybe explain how the other collection view methods work? apples dev docs don't help at all.

Comment: The closure is the code inside `({ ... })`. *Underneath* the closure means code like the useless print lines at the end of your original `fetchPosts`.

Comment: is there anyway to get the program to stall while it loads the dictionary then? I was following a tutorial and they got it to work this way so I would really like to understand what's wrong. I never learned anything about async in school :(


the correct number of posts is only printed out when it's inside the fetchPosts() right when it is appended. Is it correct to assume that the collection view doesn't load until fetchPosts() exists?

Comment: Actually it's pretty easy: The closure body (the code inside the curly braces) is executed much later in time.

Comment: I'm confused by which function we're talking about now. Are we talking about viewDidLoad, fetchPosts(), or the individual observe functions?

Comment: I added the full code with the exact oder of execution. And there is a typo: In the second closure it must be `// 9  let dict2 = snapshot2.value as! [String:NSDictionary] for(key, value) in dict2 {`

Comment: thank you for the exact order of execution, but it still doesn't work. I'm assuming self.collectionview.reloadData() calls the correct collectionView() functions, right? Any other ideas about how to handle the async call would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes. Is `dataSource` and `delegate` of the collection view connected  to the controller in Interface Builder? They have to. That's a very common omission. The async workflow is fine as suggested.

Comment: by interface builder do you mean AppDelegate? If by inference builder you mean storyboard then yes, I have connected the outlets

Comment: Not the outlets. I mean *dataSource*  and *delegate* of the collection view in the storyboard. Never mind, see the update of `viewDidLoad`. That's the same in code.